# Accessing elements inside a div and appending to a list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to store some part of my HTML in an array using jQuery.

I have this in my HTML:

```
<div id="slide">
     <div class="image">
         IMAGE 1
     </div>
     <div class="image" >
         IMAGE 2
     </div>
     <div class="image">
        IMAGE 3
     </div>
</div>
```

If I do this inside a for loop:

```
$(".image").html();
```

I get:

```
[IMAGE 1, IMAGE 2, IMAGE 3]
```

And if I do:

```
$("#slide").html();
```

I get:

```
[<div class="image">IMAGE 1</div><div class="image">IMAGE 2</div><div class="image">IMAGE 3</div>,
<div class="image">IMAGE 1</div> <div class="image">IMAGE 2</div> <div class="image">IMAGE 3</div>,
<div class="image">IMAGE 1</div><div class="image">IMAGE 2</div><div class="image">IMAGE 3</div>]
```

I want my array to look like:

```
[<div class="image">IMAGE 1</div>,
<div class="image">IMAGE 2</div>, 
<div class="image">IMAGE 3</div>]
```

which means I want the whole div to be one element.

Comment: please specify the "middle ground"

Comment: I mean, I'm either getting the stuff inside the class image, or I get the stuff inside the slide all combined. I want the stuff inside slide, but with the divs as elements. Sorry for the confusion. Maybe my desired array will help you figure out my problem.

Comment: I restructured the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you want the HTML of the DIV? Wouldn't it be easier to just work the HTML nodes?

Comment: I wanted to remove and re-add the divs. Basically like hide them; but I can't have IDs for each and so I just remove the whole div from the HTML altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the html (including the parent tag), one possible method is to clone the element, append it to a new empty div, then get the html of that div:

```
var htmlArray = [];
$(".image").each(function(index, el) {
    htmlArray.push($("<div/>").append($(el).clone()).html());
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/wjgndc30/

Also, you keep referring to Arrays in javascript using braces `{}`. Braces refer to javascript objects. Arrays are denoted by brackets `[]`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. Sorry about that error. It was a typo. I'll fix it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this:

```
var nodes = $('.image').map(function() {
  return $(this)[0];
});

// Or if you just want a normal array and not a jQuery collection
var nodes = [];

$('.image').each(function() {
    nodes.push($(this)[0]);
});
```

Hope this helps!

edit: [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0fpo8fr/)

Comment: I want a normal array but your method is giving me [object HTMLDivElement] for every element. No idea what this means.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a built-in [toArray](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) function supporting this:

```
$(".image").toArray();
```